# Stripe method expression is not of Function type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, authorization, stripe-payments

I installed stripe using `npm install --save stripe` but when I add the line `const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);` I get a warning saying stripe method expression is not of Function type. require('stripe') is underlined.  When I try and run it, I get an error

```
You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY').
```

I even tried replacing process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY with the actual key and it still gives me this error.

Comment: Make sure that you are not trying to use `stripe-node` and your secret key in a client-side application. Secret keys must be used server-side only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding `require('dotenv').config();` before `require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);`. I still get the warning but it works now.

Answer (score -1):

To use stripe in React, you must use `loadstipe` and cannot use `require` inside component.
first install this packages:

```
npm install --save @stripe/react-stripe-js @stripe/stripe-js
```

then load it using loadstripe:

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

// Make sure to call `loadStripe` outside of a component’s render to avoid
// recreating the `Stripe` object on every render.
const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_HvEeju8Kg8pqDFSjQQyyxGDb');
```

please read stripe docs for more information: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react